# The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate 0x80092012

Tags: x509, self-signed-certificate

Please help me to deal with self-signed revocation check 
I've used `makecert.exe` to [create root and client certificate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648732.aspx)

The problem is that `certutil` fails to check certificate with error 
`The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate. 0x80092012`
Here are command parameters I've used to create root

```
makecert.exe -sky signature -pe -n CN=XML_ROOT_TEST -r -sv rootMyCA.pvk -sr LocalMachine -ss Root rootMyCA.cer
```

and client certificate

```
makecert -pe -ic rootMyCA.cer -n "CN=XML_SIGN_TEST_CERT" -is Root  -sv xml_sign_test.pvk -b 01/09/2017 -e 01/09/2019 xml_sign_test.cer

pvk2pfx -pvk xml_sign_test.pvk -spc xml_sign_test.cer -pfx xml_sign_test.pfx -f
```

Then I've tried to run

```
certutil -verify -urlfetch d:\Tests\xml_sign_test.cer
```

but it fails

```
The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate. 0x80092012 (-2146885614 CRYPT_E_NO_REVOCATION_CHECK) 
Revocation check skipped -- no revocation information available  
Cannot check leaf certificate revocation status  
CertUtil: -verify command completed successfully.
```

I've tried to use makecert and generate crl revocation list as below

```
makecert -crl -n CN=XML_ROOT_TEST -sv rootMyCA.pvk rootMyCA.crl
```

then I've imported this list to the local machine\trusted root certification authorities but no luck, certutil still fails

How can I generate crl list properly?
Is it possible to generate x509 certificate without revocation check using makecert?